# How can laravel 8 use my own Users table that exists before and has data?

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, laravel-8

I have my own Users  table in database but it has not the same fields as **Users** table of laravel 8, How can laravel 8 use my own Users table that exists before and has data (my own Users table has a lot of records)?

Comment: can you more explain about your problem?

Comment: My own Users table it's not empty and has fields :                                               user_id, first_name, last_name, password, PRIVILEGE,                                                                            actif, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT                                                                              how can laravel auth use my Users table without migration?

Comment: just make the user model and set the protected variables. and for authentication, you need the email or mobile number or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your Models/User.php file.

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $table = "your_table_name";
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    const CREATED_AT = 'CREATED_AT';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'UPDATED_AT';
}
```

Now we need to add new function inside app/Http/Auth/LoginController.php like below:

```
public function username(){
    return 'email_address'; // this string is column of accounts table which we are going use for login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'user_table_name'


    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'privilege', 'actif'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```