# Laravel 8 changing users table name in App/Model with protected not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I have a relatively fresh install of laravel 8 with jetstream/fortify. I'm trying to use a pre-existing user table that has a different table name than the default 'users'.

From reading around I thought I had to just update that in the app\Model\User.php.  Which I have done as follows:

```
 class User extends Authenticatable               
 14 {                                                                                                       
 15     /**                                                                                                                                                                                                
 16     .* My custom users table                        
 17     .*/
 18     protected $table = "user";  // note here it is user not users
 19     protected $primaryKey = "user_id";
```

But when I try to register a new user, I get SQLSTATE errors that Base table or view not found...."mydb.users" doesn't exist.

So it's still looking for 'users' instead of 'user'.

Where else do I need to change this?

The documentation doesn't seem to mention anywhere else, and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318083/how-can-laravel-8-use-my-own-users-table-that-exists-before-and-has-data) stack answers seem to suggest this should be enough

Edit:
This is my config/auth.php portion

```
 67                                                                                         
 68     'providers' => [                                                                                 
 69     .   'users' => [                                               
 70     .   .   'driver' => 'eloquent',                                           
 71     .   .   'model' => App\Models\User::class,                                                                                  
 72     .   ],                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 73                    
 74     .   // 'users' => [                                               
 75     .   //     'driver' => 'database',                              
 76     .   //     'table' => 'users',                                               
 77     .   // ],                                                     
 78     ],
```

So I believe I am using the right user provider with eloquent.

Comment: have you executed ```php artisan optimize:clear``` after updating the table name, I don't think its required but just a hunch

Comment: And is `eloquent` selected as your user providers driver in auth config?

Comment: You also need to change the table name in migration of users table.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449076/laravel-5-4-change-authentication-users-table-name/44449119

Comment: @MAY Yes, I believe eloquent is selected in auth config.  And I tried the optimize:clear but still same results. I added in my auth config above.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat The name was changed in the migration already. The link you provided doesn't seem to say much more than use the protected field in the model.

Comment: does this occur during validation before registering a user, if so then update your validation rule to match with the new table when identifying unique users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Validation rules for unicity of the email have the table name hardcoded in it (it happens before initialising any model so it makes sense in a way).

something that looks like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'email|unique:users', //<- notice here that the database table name is hardcoded
    'password' => 'required',
]);
```

If you're using default validator, then you need to replicate it and change that line.

Comment: Thank you! This was it.